# Items in Vuetify list subgroup not stacking vertically

Tags: list, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've taken over a Vue (2.5.22) app with Vuetify (1.4.3), and the app has a left nav that uses `v-list` and `v-list-group` elements:

```
<template>
  <v-list dark class="ap-sidebar-applist">
    <v-list-group
      class="ap-sidebar-group"
      v-for="(item, i) in items"
      :key="i"
      :prepend-icon="item.icon"
      :value="item.visible"
      @click="onClick(item)"
    >
      <v-list-tile slot="activator">
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>

      <v-list-group
        v-if="item.children"
        sub-group
        no-action
        class="ap-sidebar-subgroup"
      >
        <v-list-tile slot="activator"
          v-for="(subMenu, j) in item.children"
          :key="j"
          @click="onClick(subMenu, true)"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ subMenu.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ subMenu.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list-group>

    </v-list-group>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

```
export default {
  name: 'TheLeftSidebarAppList',
  props: {
    visible: Boolean,
  },
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        icon: 'group',
        title: 'Users',
        routeTo: 'UserEdit',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        visible: true,
        children: [
          {
            icon: 'send',
            title: 'Send Quick Alert',
            method: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        icon: 'domain',
        title: 'Tenants',
        routeTo: 'TenantEdit',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        visible: false,
        children: [
          {
            icon: 'fingerprint',
            title: 'Manage Biometrics',
            method: 1,
          },
          {
            icon: 'email',
            title: 'Manage Templates',
            method: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        icon: 'assessment',
        title: 'Reports',
        routeTo: 'WorkspaceReports',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        visible: false,
      },
      {
        icon: 'settings',
        title: 'Server Configuration',
        routeTo: null,
        method: 2,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: false,
        visible: false,
      },
      {
        icon: 'trending_up',
        title: 'Performance',
        routeTo: 'WorkspacePerformance',
        method: null,
        superOnly: true,
        taCanView: true,
        visible: false,
      },
    ],
  }),
}
```

I want to add two items under the `Tenants` item by adding a `children` array in the data:

```
      {
        icon: 'domain',
        title: 'Tenants',
        routeTo: 'TenantEdit',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        visible: false,
        children: [
          {
            icon: 'fingerprint',
            title: 'Manage Biometrics',
            method: 1,
          },
          {
            icon: 'email',
            title: 'Manage Templates',
            method: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
```

but when it is displayed, the children items are displayed horizontally, instead of being stacked vertically:

[image]

From everything I've seen, they should stack vertically, but they don't. What do I need to do to get them to be stacked vertically?

**UPDATE:** This component is included in a parent component that wraps this in a `<v-navigation-drawer>` component:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="visible"
    fixed
    app
    dark
    class="primary"
  >
    <v-toolbar flat class="ap-img-toolbar">
      <v-list class="pa-0">
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <img src="/images/LogoSmall.png">

          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-toolbar>

    <TheLeftSidebarAppList />

  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Comment: Who would downvote my answer... a completely legit working solution and it gets downvoted... insanity.

Comment: try wrapping your `<v-list>` with `<v-navigation-drawer>`

Comment: @DjSh Actually, it already is. This component is a child component, and the parent component has the `<v-navigation-drawer>` element.

```

Comment: what does `class="ap-sidebar-subgroup"` do?

Comment: @DjSh It just sets the `background` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `slot="activator"` from the `<v-list-tile>` containing the children and that will take care of the horizontal issue.

I have created a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/BEPVag?editors=1010) using your example.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks great in your Codepen, but falls apart in my app, so I think there is some other stuff going on that's causing the problem.

Comment: how does it fall apart? did you also remove the 2nd `v-list-group`? I commented it in the codepen and added the condition to the `v-list-tile`

Comment: Ok, that works. The only issue is that VS Code is saying that the `v-if="item.children` line should be moved to the wrapper element, but since the `v-list-group` element isn't there, this is the only place to put it. A little CSS to indent the submenu items a bit, and I'm good to go.  Thanks!!

Comment: happy to hear that :)